# How to handle "don't allow" permission in iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, ios-extensions, imessage-extension

I am developing one iMessage Extension in which I need to use photos from Photo Library, but here it generated one use case for which I am not getting any solution.

When OS ask for Photo permission access to user, then user set `Don't allow`, after that how to set permission on for iMessage Extension.

[image]

But I am not able to find settings menu for iMessage Extension app from which user set photo permission on.

**NOTE: I am developing iMessage Extension without parent iOS App.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable this permission later from privacy setting. Please check below path to enable that permission

Settings -> Privacy -> Photos -> < Your app >